# Evaluating Contour Integrals (sine, exponential)

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, contour-integration

**Question**

a) $\int_{\Gamma}z\sin(z^2)dz$, where $\Gamma : \gamma(t):= \sqrt{3}t+2(1-t)i$, where $0 \leq t < 1$.

b) Calculate $\int_{\Gamma} \frac{\sin(z)}{z^2-5}+ \frac{e^-z}{z-2}dz$, where $ \Gamma : |z-12i|= \frac{1}{4} $.

**My Answer**

a) I don't know how I should start this part. I have tried differentiating $\gamma(t)$ and using the formula $\int_{0}^{1}(\gamma(t)\sin(\gamma(t)^2)\gamma'(t)dt$ but this becomes very complicated. I have also tried using $\int_{\Gamma} f(z)dz=F(q)-F(p)$, where $p$ and $q$ are the initial and final points of $\Gamma$ but this didn't work either.

b) For this part I think you can use Cauchy's integral formula but don't know how to do this. Would I need to make $f(z)$ into one function and then calculate the residues for the poles that are within the interior of $\Gamma$? I also just wanted to check is $\Gamma$ a circle centre $12i$ and radius $\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: a) What part of that second approach didn't work out? b) Yes, that's what $\Gamma$ is. Are there any poles/singularities within that circle? If not, what does the integral end up being?

Comment: I couldn't calculate $F= \int f(z) dz$. If there are no poles does the integral just become $0$?

Comment: For a), you should be able to calculate the integral. Try letting $u = z^2, du = 2z$. Then you get $\int \frac 1 2 \sin(u)\, du$. For b), you're correct, so you don't even need to calculate any residues.

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful!